# call_user_func_array() error on my blog

Tags: errors

I recently encountered this error on my blog and I am on a lookout for helpful tips to fix it. Please help me fix this. Here is the error

> `Warning: call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, array must have exactly two members in /home/customer/www/mydomain.com/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php on line 287`

Here is the block of code: The line marked out by ">>>>>>>>" is line 287

```
// Avoid the array_slice() if possible.
            if ( 0 == $the_['accepted_args'] ) {
                $value = call_user_func( $the_['function'] );
            } elseif ( $the_['accepted_args'] >= $num_args ) {
>>>>>>>>>>>>    $value = call_user_func_array( $the_['function'], $args );
            } else {
                $value = call_user_func_array( $the_['function'], array_slice( $args, 0, (int) $the_['accepted_args'] ) );
            }
```

Comment: Did you disable all plugins then re-enable them one by one to discover which plugin the problem is in?

Comment: This means that something is registering a hook incorrectly. There should be a longer call stack: look down that for something that's calling do_action or apply_filters to work out which action or filter this is, then search your site for that string to find all the places you're registering one of these hooks. One of those is wrong.